# What's the docker-compose equivalent for docker run --publish-all?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Docker provides the option [`--publish-all`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) for `docker run`.

```
--publish-all , -P :        Publish all exposed ports to random ports
```

What would be the equivalent when using `docker-compose`? I've looked through the docker compose cli and yml file docs and can't find anything like that.

For context, I am looking to do this with Elasticsearch as recommended by their documentation for deploying to production. [See #4 here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docker.html#_notes_for_production_use_and_defaults).

> The image exposes TCP ports 9200 and 9300. For clusters it is
>   recommended to randomize the published ports with `--publish-all`,
>   unless you are pinning one container per host.

Comment: (Pinning one container per host, or even running databases outside of Docker, isn't a bad idea.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. After I created this question I realized that what you said is probably going to be the case, but I figured that the chosen answer is still nice to know from a docker perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option like this available.

But this can be done with `docker-compose.yaml` configuration.

You can specify [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) in the following format:

```
ports:
 - "9200"
 - "9300"
```

Then, on `docker-compose up -d` it will publish this ports to random host ports (from local test run):

```
~ ➜ docker-compose ps
       Name                     Command               State                        Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
elasticsearch_test   /usr/local/bin/docker-entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:32769->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->9300/tcp
```

And you can query it like this:

```
~ ➜ curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:32769
```

Comment: How to expose this container to outside network? I tried bridge network and port forwarding but could only access inside the network